# set maximum of items that you can make in function

Tags: php, function

How can I say in/with the follow (see below) function that you can make max 3 items? And if you will make more than three items the function will stop and you get a warning?

```
function addSection() {
global $compid;
    $sectionOb = new Item();
    $sectionOb->i_id_pk = $sectionOb->newId();
    $sectionOb->i_mod_comp_id_fk = $compid;
    $sectionOb->c_titel = '';
    $sectionOb->c_content = '';
    $sectionOb->i_sort = $sectionOb->newSort($compid);
    $sectionOb->insert();
}
```

---

```
if($action == 'add') {  
    addSection();
}


<a href="<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ?>&amp;action=add" />new section</a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are not too concerned about URL spoofing, I would add a counter variable in the URL which is passed to the addSection() method like so:

```
function addSection($count) {
    if ($count >= 3) { return $count; }
    global $compid;
    $sectionOb = new Item();
    $sectionOb->i_id_pk = $sectionOb->newId();
    $sectionOb->i_mod_comp_id_fk = $compid;
    $sectionOb->c_titel = '';
    $sectionOb->c_content = '';
    $sectionOb->i_sort = $sectionOb->newSort($compid);
    $sectionOb->insert();

    // Return incremented count
    return $count + 1;
}
```

---

```
// Retrieve the last count from the URL
$count = isset($_GET['count']) ? intval($_GET['count']) : 0;

// Increment the count if the action is add and the addSection method suceedes
if($action == 'add') {  
    $count = addSection($count); 
}

// Add count to the URL so we know what it is
<a href="<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ?>&action=add&count=<?php echo $count; ?>" />new section</a>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a static counter variable:

```
function limited() {
    static $invocationcount = 0;
    ++$invocationcount;

    if($invocationcount <= 3) {
        echo "You have called this function $invocationcount times.";
    }
    else {
        echo "Stop doing that!";
    }
}
```

**[See it in action](http://ideone.com/tJ9FT)**.

Answer (score 0):

**Thanks a lot for help!!** I have do it as follow:

```
function limit() {
global $compid;
$i = 0;
++$i;
$a_all = page1::page2Id($compid);
$i = sizeof($a_all);

if($i <= 2) { 
    $sectionOb = section();
    $sectionOb->i_id_pk = $sectionOb->newId();
    $sectionOb->i_mod_comp_id_fk = $compid;
    $sectionOb->c_titel = '';
    $sectionOb->c_content = '';
    $sectionOb->i_sort = $sectionOb->newSort($compid);
    $sectionOb->insert();
    return true;
} 
else { 
return false;
}
```

}